# Update select using the max of one column Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I'm changing a db structure. I'm moving a column, 'size', from table_B to table_A.
Table_B can have multiple entries referencing table_A.a_id

I want to update the new 'size' column in table_A from table_B with the row with the highest b_id.

So I can use Max() and group by to select just the highest b_ids for each a_id.

```
SELECT max(b_id)
FROM table_B
GROUP BY a_id;
```

But I'm not sure how to fit that in with the update select

```
UPDATE table_A
SET table_A.size = table_B.size
FROM table_A, table_B
WHERE table_A.a_id = table_B.a_id
AND table_B.b_id = 
(
    max...
);
```

edit:
I realise now this actually isn't an update select, my first attempt was

How table_B looks and the expected result in table_A

```
table_A
a_id        | size
-------------------------
1           | 5678
2           | 456

table_B
b_id        | a_id       | size
--------------------------------------
1           | 1          | 1234
2           | 1          | 5678
3           | 2          | 456
```

Comment: Do **not** repeat the target table in the `from` clause.

Comment: try putting first select to CTE with group by and then `update from CTE where` ?..

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write a `select` to get the size you want:

```
select distinct on (b.a_id) b.a_id, b.size
from tableb b
order by b.a_id, b.b_id desc;
```

Next, incorporate this into the `update`:

```
update tablea a
    set size = b.size
    from (select distinct on (b.a_id) b.*
          from tableb b
          order by b.a_id, b.b_id desc
         ) b
    where a.a_id = b.a_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following query

```
UPDATE table_A 
SET table_A.size = 
    ( SELECT table_B.size
      FROM table_B B1
      WHERE table_A.a_id = B1.a_id AND
      B1.b_id = (SELECT max(b_id) FROM table_B B2 WHERE table_A.a_id=B2.a_id))
```

Comment: table_A doesn't reference table_B. table_B references table_A.
So table_A.b_id doesn't exist

Comment: You can't reference `table_b` in the `set` clause like that.